# Oracle procedure for send single email from query result

Tags: oracle, procedure

My Oracle procedures are not working as expected, kindly advise which part needs to update.

Expectation: The query result will send in single emails.
For example, the result from the query has 3 entries.
However, the email sending with 3 separate emails instead of 1 email content of 3 entries.

```
v_subject := 'Missing info';
for email in 
  (
  select * 
  from Info WHERE info_status is null
  )
loop
  v_message := 'Name' || email.name || ' --> '|| email.status || ' '|| email.year || ' ';

SEND_MAIL(
SENDER => v_From,
RECIPIENT => v_TO,
SUBJECT => v_subject,
MESSAGE => v_message);
END LOOP email;
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, the code inside the loop runs once for each row returned from the query.
Hint: Build the MESSAGE and RECIPIENT values for each row returned, then send only one e-mail at the end.